# vlc player fast forward and backward features in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I use VLC player in my movie app. I can play video and adjust video volume. 
I would like to make Fast Forward and Backward with the speed of 2x, 3x, 4x. 
I really don't know how to implement this. :( 
Could anyone help me? I already search examples in google. I don't found it yet.

Comment: How do you use VLC in your app? Give us more details please.

Comment: I Used Mobile VLC Kit to play the video. Actually video files are stored in server. Need to get those files and play on VLC Player. Playing is working fine but i need to give the option to the user to Forward and Backward with the speed of 2x, 3x, 4x. I used below method when the user taps on player view to play the video

Comment: override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        waitingToStop = false
        if mediaPlayer.state == VLCMediaPlayerState.Stopped {
diaPlayer.media = VLCMedia(URL: NSURL(string: vdpStreamURL!))
            mediaPlayer.play()
         
        } else {
            if mediaPlayer.playing {
       
                mediaPlayer.pause()
            }else {
                uiIVPlayandPause.image = UIImage(named: "calllogdata_pause")
                mediaPlayer.play()

Comment: i called few notofications like "func mediaPlayerStateChanged(aNotification: NSNotification!)" and func mediaPlayerTimeChanged(aNotification: NSNotification!)